# java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: "Some(2014-05-14T14:40:25.950)"

Tags: date, simpledateformat, datetime-parsing

I need to fetch the date from a file. 
Below is my spark program:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession
import scala.xml.XML
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat


object Active6Month {
  def main(args:Array[String]){
    val format  = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'hh:mm:ss.SSS")
    val format1  = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM")
    val spark = SparkSession.builder.appName("Active6Months").master("local").getOrCreate()
    val data = spark.read.textFile("D:\\BGH\\StackOverFlow\\Posts.xml").rdd

    val date = data.filter{line => {
      line.toString().trim().startsWith("<row")
    }}.filter{line=>{
      line.contains("PostTypeId=\"1\"")
    }}.map{line=>{
      val xml = XML.loadString(line)
      var closedDate = format1.format(format.parse(xml.attribute("ClosedDate").toString())).toString()
      (closedDate,1)
    }}.reduceByKey(_+_)

    date.foreach(println)
    spark.stop
   }
}
```

And I am getting this error:

> java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: "Some(2014-05-14T14:40:25.950)"

The format of date in file is perfect i.e:

```
CreationDate="2014-05-13T23:58:30.457"
```

But in error it shows the String `"Some"` attached to it.

And my other question is why same working in below code:

```
val date = data.filter{line => {
      line.toString().trim().startsWith("<row")
    }}.filter{line=>{
      line.contains("PostTypeId=\"1\"")
    }}.flatMap{line=>{
      val xml = XML.loadString(line)
      xml.attribute("ClosedDate")
    }}.map{line=>{
      (format1.format(format.parse(line.toString())).toString(),1)

    }}.reduceByKey(_+_)
```

Comment: I recommend you avoid the `SimpleDateFormat` class. It is not only long outdated, it is also notoriously troublesome. Today we have so much better in [`java.time`, the modern Java date and time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/).

Answer (score 1):

My guess is that `xml.attribute("ClosedDate").toString()` **is actually** returning a string containing `Some` attached to it. Have you debugged that to make sure?

Maybe you shouldn't use `toString()`, but instead, get the attribute **value**, by using the proper method.

Or you can do it the "ugly" way and include "Some" in the pattern:

```
val format = new SimpleDateFormat("'Some('yyyy-MM-dd'T'hh:mm:ss.SSS')'")
```

Your second approach works because (and that's a guess because I don't code in Scala), probably the `xml.attribute("ClosedDate")` method returns an object, and calling `toString()` on this object returns the string with "Some" attached to it (why? ask the API authors). But when you use `map` on this object, it sets the `line` variable to the correct value (without the "Some" part).

Comment: Its working fine when I pass the value to flatmap and then in map

Comment: Have you **printed** the value of `xml.attribute("ClosedDate").toString()`? It's probably returning a string with "Some" attached to it.

Comment: Yes it is returning but the why below code is working:
  val date = data.filter{line => {
      line.toString().trim().startsWith("<row")
    }}.filter{line=>{
      line.contains("PostTypeId=\"1\"")
    }}.flatMap{line=>{
      val xml = XML.loadString(line)
      xml.attribute("ClosedDate")
    }}.map{line=>{
      (format1.format(format.parse(line.toString())).toString(),1)
      
    }}.reduceByKey(_+_)

Comment: Another detail is that `format1.format` method already returns a `String`, so there's no need to call `toString()` on its result. Unless scala behaves differently from Java in this aspect...